# How to keep dist/ folder only in master branch with Git

Tags: angularjs, heroku, github, build, gruntjs

I'm currently working with Yeoman AngularJS Generator for my student project at School. Before I deploy my project to Heroku (I'm using [heroku-buildpack-static](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static)), I need to run `$ grunt build` to build entire source code and automatically put it in **`dist/`** folder. I must to include **`dist/`** by removing `dist/` row in `.gitignore` file, but I don't want to push these code in `dist/` folder to another branches.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to have fundamental structural differences between branches. A better way to achieve what you want to do is to perform this build step on Heroku, if that's the place you need it to happen.

You can run this build and create this directory using an NPM `postinstall` hook.

Check my answer to this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42237745/673882

Comment: Hi Nathan Loyer, I got it. Thanks for your answer.