# Error starting Node/Koa application on Heroku related to webpack and babel-loader

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, babeljs

I have building a small app with Node.js and Koa. I am using the Cloud9 IDE and I can run my application directly from Cloud 9 without any problems. I am trying to deploy onto Heroku (via github). However, I am receiving errors when the application starts on Heroku that I cannot fix. I think it is a problem with how I have setup the directories and Heroku can't find the dependancy modules but I am new to Node/Koa and can't figure out how to correct this. My code is here: https://github.com/infornite/n4nite-api

**Error Log from Heroku:**
[image]

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const externals = fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(x => ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1)
    .reduce((obj, mod) => {
        obj[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
        return obj;
    }, {});

externals['koa-neo4j/check'] = 'commonjs koa-neo4j/check';
externals['koa-neo4j/preprocess'] = 'commonjs koa-neo4j/preprocess';
externals['koa-neo4j/postprocess'] = 'commonjs koa-neo4j/postprocess';
externals['koa-neo4j/debug'] = 'commonjs koa-neo4j/debug';
externals['koa-neo4j/util'] = 'commonjs koa-neo4j/util';

const plugins = [];

const config = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: {
        './server': './src/server.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    externals: externals,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    plugins: plugins
};

module.exports = config;
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "n4nite-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "An API for the Infornite Metadata Management Tool",
  "credits": "koa-neo4j-starter-kit / Keyvan Mir Mohammad Sadeghi <keyvan.m.sadeghi@gmail.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "jsnext:main": "./src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./src --fix",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "start": "npm run build && DEV=1 node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js",
    "serve": "npm run build && node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Keyvan Mir Mohammad Sadeghi <keyvan.m.sadeghi@gmail.com>",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode": "^6.11.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "eslint": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.27"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "koa-neo4j": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not install `devDependencies` by default ([Node.js devDependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies)). You have several possibilities to work around that issue:

- Put the necessary dependencies to `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`.
- Disable production mode with: `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`.
- Build locally and push the built files directly.

Pick the one you prefer, but generally it would be best to build it locally so you don't need to install all the dependencies when deploying.

Comment: Thanks so much - I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Another alternative that will allow you to build on Heroku is to script a `postinstall` operation that loads dev dependencies, builds, then cleans up the dev dependencies. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42237745/673882