# Heroku - Node with Gulp & Browserify: Error Cannot find module from

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, gulp, browserify

I'm using Gulp for building all my assets. For Javascript, I have a task which uses Browserify to solve all my code dependencies.

When I'm running my project locally everything works perfectly. But, when deployed in heroku, Gulp fails with the following error:

```
2017-04-21T20:35:28.370935+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module  './components/feed' from '/app/client/web/public/dev/js'
2017-04-21T20:35:28.370935+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
2017-04-21T20:35:28.370936+00:00 app[web.1]:     at load (/app/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
2017-04-21T20:35:28.370937+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onex (/app/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
2017-04-21T20:35:28.370937+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
2017-04-21T20:35:28.370938+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

This is the Gulp task

```
gulp.task('bundle', () => {
  const javascriptFiles = [
    {
      src: './client/web/public/dev/js/main.js',
      outDir: './client/web/public/production/js',
      outFile: 'main.bundle.js'
    }
  ]
  javascriptFiles.forEach((file) => {
    const bundler = browserify({
      entries: [ file.src ],
      extensions: ['.js'],
      paths: ['./node_modules','./client/web/public/dev/js']
    })
    .transform(coffeeify)
    .transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015'] })

    createBundle(bundler, file)
  })
})

function createBundle (bundler, file) {
  const src = path.join(__dirname, file.src)
  const outFile = path.join(__dirname, file.outFile)
  const outDir = path.join(__dirname, file.outDir)
  const sourceMapDir = 'maps'

  bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source(src))
    .pipe(buffer()) // Convert to gulp pipeline
    .pipe(rename(outFile))
    // Sourc Map
    .pipe(sourceMaps.init({ loadMaps : true }))
    .pipe(sourceMaps.write(sourceMapDir)) // save
    // Write result to output directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outDir))
    .pipe(livereload()) // Reload browser if relevant
}
```

This is my current project organization (for the client module)

```
.
├── app.js
├── gulpfile.js
└── client
    └── web
        ├── public
        │   ├── dev
        │   │   ├── js
        │   │   │   ├── main.js
        │   │   │   │   ├── utils
        │   │   │   │   │   ├── random.js
        │   │   │   │   ├── components
        │   │   │   │   │   ├── feed
        │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── index.js
```

This is the main module from client/web/public/dev/js/main.js that requires the feed module and fails:

```
const Feed = require('./components/feed')
Feed.doWhatever(...)
```

This is a snippet for the feed module:

```
const Random = require('../../utils/random)

class Feed {
    // Rest of class
}

module.exports = Feed
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, your `devDependencies` in `package.json` don't get loaded when your `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`. By default, Heroku sets that to production. So you have three options, in my opinion, in order from worst to best.

1. Set your `NODE_ENV` env var in Heroku to something else. (`staging` or anything other than `production`) Then your devDependencies will load, grunt will run, but you'll have all those libraries in your Heroku build. And you shouldn't run a production app in this mode.
2. Move the necessary devDependencies to the `dependencies` section of your `package.json`. Same as before, those libraries will still be in your production app, but at least your `NODE_ENV` will be accurate.
3. Use a `postinstall` script to load devDependencies, run your build, and remove the devDependencies before launch. See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42237745/673882